# aioredis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection closed by server

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, python-asyncio, redis-py

I get this error randomly with redis on heroku.

```
aioredis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection closed by server.
```

this is the full trace:

```
2023-03-25T23:34:34.116795+00:00 app[web.1]: There was an exception checking if the field exists in the hashmap: await wasn't used with future
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117607+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-03-25 23:34:34,117] ERROR in app: Exception on /thelio_bot [POST]
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117608+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117608+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 1422, in get_connection
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117609+00:00 app[web.1]: if await connection.can_read():
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117609+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 893, in can_read
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117609+00:00 app[web.1]: return await self._parser.can_read(timeout)
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117609+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 479, in can_read
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117610+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ConnectionError(SERVER_CLOSED_CONNECTION_ERROR)
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117610+00:00 app[web.1]: aioredis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Connection closed by server.
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117611+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117611+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117611+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117612+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117612+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/thelioapp/redis_factory.py", line 300, in field_exists
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117612+00:00 app[web.1]: hash_exists = await redis_conn.exists(self.redis_key)
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117613+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioredis/client.py", line 1082, in execute_command
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117613+00:00 app[web.1]: conn = self.connection or await pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117614+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 1425, in get_connection
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117614+00:00 app[web.1]: await connection.disconnect()
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117614+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py", line 806, in disconnect
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117620+00:00 app[web.1]: await self._writer.wait_closed()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117620+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/asyncio/streams.py", line 343, in wait_closed
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117620+00:00 app[web.1]: await self._protocol._get_close_waiter(self)
2023-03-25T23:34:34.117620+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
```

This happens when executing a redis command:

```
async def update_hashmap(self):
    redis_conn = await self.get_redis_conn()

    try:
        await redis_conn.hset(self.redis_key, self.field, self.value)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"There was an exception updating/adding to the hashmap: {e}")
        raise Exception
```

happens on line:

```
await redis_conn.hset(self.redis_key, self.field, self.value)
```

my get_redis_conn function is like so:

```
executed_redis_pool = False
main_redis_pool = None
def create_redis_pool():
    global executed_redis_pool
    global main_redis_pool
    if not executed_redis_pool:
        executed_redis_pool=True
        main_redis_pool = aioredis.ConnectionPool.from_url(os.environ["REDIS_URI_PROD"])
    else:
        print("Redis pool already executed")

create_redis_pool()


async def get_redis_conn():
    redis_conn = await aioredis.Redis(connection_pool=main_redis_pool, health_check_interval=30, db=0, decode_responses=True)
    return redis_conn
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
I've tried to investigate the broken connections and latency `redis-cli --latency` but ultimately what has helped me is retry, eg:

```
def _get_aioredis_connection():
    from redis.asyncio.retry import Retry

    return aioredis.client.Redis(
        host=get_core_settings().redis_host,
        port=get_core_settings().redis_port,
        max_connections=10_000,  # aioredis default is 2**31                                                                                                          
        socket_timeout=4.0,
        socket_connect_timeout=3.0,
        socket_keepalive=True,
        retry=Retry(NoBackoff(), 3),
        retry_on_error=[
            ConnectionError,
        ],
        auto_close_connection_pool=False,
        health_check_interval=30,
    )


@functools.cache
def get_aioredis_connection():
    return _get_aioredis_connection()
```

It would be interesting to see your redis url kwargs as well as code that uses your connection. Be aware that mixing "single_connection_client" eg, `async with my_redis_conn...` and access using pool `my_redis_conn.bla...` can also cause problems.